# How to find obsolete Java version users in a windows server

Tags: windows, java

I deploy newer version of Java in windows server. Then I made new version the default one. But How can I find apps, programs, services, that are using older, obsolete java versions, before I unistall them? Is there any trace I can keep active to find them?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [WMI command-line (WMIC)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic), because as a command line tool it works both with Window Server Core and Desktop Experience. E.g.

```
wmic process where "name like '%java%'" get ExecutablePath,CommandLine
```

If the `ExecutablePath` is the binary for the older version, then it is running on that version, and the `CommandLine` probably reveals the Java application.